# Can we get the active buttons in an array in jquery?

Tags: jquery, arrays, button

```
var btnps = $('.btnp').active.toArray() ;
for(var i=0; i<btnps.length; i++)
{
   var gtext = btnps[i].closest("div").find("p.full-title").text();
}
```

Can we get the active buttons in an array and then use that array and find the text above the button like above code?

```
<div>
  <p class="full-title">Welcome</p>
</div>
<button class="btnp">SELECT</button>

<div>
  <p class="full-title">Hello</p>
</div>
<button class="btnp">SELECT</button>

<div>
  <p class="full-title">Hi</p>
</div>
<button class="btnp">SELECT</button>
```

css for active buttons :

```
.btnp.active{ background-color:#000000; }
```

Comment: What do you mean by active?

Comment: selecting only active buttons

Comment: How do you define active buttons?

Comment: By active you mean not disabled? Is it class active?

Comment: I have added the code for active button in css. So thats not the problem

Comment: .btnp.active{
background-color:#000000;
}

Comment: Yes. When the button is clicked by the user, it gets active and its background black color is applied through css.

Comment: tried `$('.btnp.active').toArray()` ?

Comment: I will try this and let you know. Thank you

Comment: You defined `active` class in `css` but you have not any element with this class!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Refer Below fiddle.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/raskarvishal7/jdk4td5q/1/)

```
**HTML**

<div>
  <p class="full-title">Welcome</p>
</div>
<button type="button" class=" btn btnp active">SELECT</button>

<div>
  <p class="full-title">Hello</p>
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btnp">SELECT</button>

<div>
  <p class="full-title">Hi</p>
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btnp">SELECT</button>]

**CSS**

.btnp.active{ 
  background-color:#000000;
  color:#fff;
}


**JS**

var btnps = $('.btnp.active');

for(var i=0; i<btnps.length; i++)
{
   var gtext = $(btnps[i]).prev().find("p.full-title").text();
   console.log(gtext)
}


$('.btnp').click(function(){
    $('.btnp').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

No need of array. You can directly loop the element with [`each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) in jQuery. And you can simply find the previous element of current element.

```js
$('.active').each(function(){
  console.log($(this).prev('div').find('p').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p class="full-title">Welcome</p>
</div>
<button class="btnp active">SELECT</button>

<div>
  <p class="full-title">Hello</p>
</div>
<button class="btnp active">SELECT</button>

<div>
  <p class="full-title">Hi</p>
</div>
<button class="btnp active">SELECT</button>
```

Comment: This is not `array`  *Can we get the active buttons in an array in jquery?* Why no need, when OP want this?

Comment: @Pedram OP actually want to find the text previous to the button. He have mentioned "Can we get the active buttons in an array and then use that array and find the text above the button like above code?"

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the solution:**

1. Take the button array `$('.btnp.active').toArray()`
2. Find `previous` `div` using `$(btnps[i]).prev('div')`
3. Get text using
   `$(btnps[i]).prev('div').find("p.full-title").text();`
4. Push into result `array array.push(gtext)`

```js
var btnps = $('.btnp.active').toArray() ;
var array  = [];

for(var i=0; i<btnps.length; i++)
{
   var gtext = $(btnps[i]).prev('div').find("p.full-title").text();
   array.push(gtext)
}

alert(array + " are active")
```

```css
.active{
background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p class="full-title">Welcome</p>
</div>
<button class="btnp">SELECT</button>

<div>
  <p class="full-title">Hello</p>
</div>
<button class="btnp active">SELECT</button>

<div>
  <p class="full-title">Hi</p>
</div>
<button class="btnp active">SELECT</button>
```

**Please run the above code**

[**Here is a working DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/hHDBOy3Xtcn3nRcXZVMc?p=preview)